# Convery a String to EPOCH MySQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation, epoch

I have a table with three columns, birth_day, birth_month, and birth_year.  All three are INT.  I'd like to CONCAT() these and convert them to EPOCH and save them back into a new column.

To CONCAT() these values I've used

```
SELECT CONCAT(birth_month, "/", birth_day, "/", birth_year) AS new_birthday from birthdaytable
```

I'm getting stuck on how I would convert this to EPOCH.  I would try and cast new_birthday to a day then perform some calculations on this but some of the years are outside of the DATE/YEAR range for MySQL (some are before 1901)

Thoughts?

Comment: Why won't you use simply a DATE-column? "The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.", see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Comment: 1901 is the limit of a 32-bit UNIX `time_t` type epoch value. Why are you using these, especially for dates? The time-zone is extremely important here and will wildly swing the interpretation of this value around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to change your `CONCAT` first, and combine that with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(birth_year, "-", IF(birth_month < 10, CONCAT('0', birth_month), birth_month), "-", IF(birth_day < 10, CONCAT('0', birth_day), birth_day))) AS newField from birthdaytable
```

Comment: Updated to meet your need of padding with zeros

Comment: Thanks, that works for the most part, but some UNIX_TIMESTAMP()'s are still returning as 0's.  If I remove the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() just to view the concat it looks like the dates are formatted correctly and I can't tell any rhyme or reason for them not working.  For example "1981-12-27" converts fine while "1934-02-05" returns 0.00

Comment: @user2229544 that's because unix timestamps start at `1970-01-01`. If you're dealing with dates before that, you can't use unix timestamps. As mentioned in one of the comments above, you may be better off using the `DATE` datatype for your new column.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30 10:30:19');-> 1196440219
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like this will work but I didn't notice something until I used your query.  The months are either single or double digit.  So 10, 11, and 12 convert fine, any single digit months don't, is their any easy way to check for a single digit month and if so add a leading 0?